# how to get highest record of every 10 minute data sql query

Tags: sql-server

```
 WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY cdt, DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, cdt), 0)
                ORDER BY cdt DESC 
             )
    FROM brands
)
SELECT
    brandID, brandname, cdt, udt, brandstatus, addedby
FROM Cte
WHERE rn = 1 and cdt between '2013-11-01 00:00:00' and '2013-11-16 00:00:00'  ORDER BY brandId
```

my table is like below:

```
ID  brandname     cdt                          udt  brandstatus addedby
1   khasim  2013-11-01 19:14:18.120 2013-11-15 19:14:18.123 1   1
2   khasim  2013-11-01 19:14:18.121 2013-11-15 19:14:18.123 1   1
3   khasim  2013-11-01 19:14:18.122 2013-11-15 19:14:18.123 1   1          
4   khasim  2013-11-01 19:14:18.123 2013-11-15 19:14:18.123 1   1
5   khasim  2013-11-02 19:17:57.700 2013-11-15 19:17:57.700 1   2
6   tanveer 2013-11-03 19:18:05.947 2013-11-15 19:18:05.947 1   2
7   abcdef  2013-11-04 20:50:06.783 2013-11-15 20:50:06.787 1   4
```

I want to get every n minute data in the range of x hours/days. if n=10 it should return the highest value of 10 minute interval between x=5 hours.

[image]

Comment: Highest value of what exactly? `cdt`? So one entry at 12:00, one at 12:03 and one at 12:11 with the interval set to 10 minutes would always return the one at 12:03 and at 12:11?

Comment: yes highest value of cdt

Comment: A question with a screenshot of itself included... now I've seen it all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for n = 10

```
rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, cdt) / 10
                ORDER BY cdt DESC)
```

Comment: its giving every one minute interval if i do it like this.

Comment: you have tried that and it is not giving the expected result ?

Comment: Since the brandname grouping was removed from the question, I think `PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, cdt) / 10` would be enough.

Comment: oh... it was removed. I will edit accordingly, thanks joachim

Answer (score 0):

You could try grouping by a datediff value like

**(edited)**:

```
WITH cte as (
 SELECT ID, brandname, cdt, udt, brandstatus, addedby,
 DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2000-01-01', cdt)/10 step
 FROM #tbl
)
SELECT ID, brandname, cdt, udt, brandstatus, addedby FROM cte a
WHERE ID=(SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM cte b 
          WHERE b.brandname=a.brandname
            AND b.step=a.step
          ORDER BY b.cdt DESC)
```

Output:

```
ID brandname cdt                 udt                 brandstatus addedby 
-- --------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------- ------- 
3  khasim    2013-11-01 19:14:18 2013-11-15 19:14:18 1           1       
5  khasim    2013-11-02 19:17:57 2013-11-15 19:17:57 1           2       
6  tanveer   2013-11-03 19:18:05 2013-11-15 19:18:05 1           2       
7  abcdef    2013-11-04 20:50:06 2013-11-15 20:50:06 1           4
```

**(2. edit):**

```
WITH cte as (
 SELECT ID, brandname, cdt, udt, brandstatus, addedby,
 DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2000-01-01', cdt)/10 step
 FROM #tbl
)
SELECT ID, brandname, cdt, udt, brandstatus, addedby FROM cte a
WHERE ID=(SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM cte b 
          WHERE b.step=a.step
          ORDER BY b.cdt DESC)
```

Output:

```
ID brandname cdt           udt                       brandstatus addedby 
-- --------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------- ------- 
3  khasim    2013-11-01 19:14:18 2013-11-15 19:14:18 1           1       
5  khasim    2013-11-02 19:17:57 2013-11-15 19:17:57 1           2       
6  tanveer   2013-11-03 19:18:05 2013-11-15 19:18:05 1           2       
7  abcdef    2013-11-04 20:50:06 2013-11-15 20:50:06 1           4
```

**(3. edit)** largest `cdt` within 16 days:

```
WITH cte as (
 SELECT ID, brandname, cdt, udt, brandstatus, addedby,
 DATEDIFF(day,'2013-11-01', cdt)/16 step
 FROM #tbl
)
SELECT ID, brandname, cdt, udt, brandstatus, addedby, step FROM cte a
WHERE ID=(SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM cte b 
          WHERE b.step=a.step
          ORDER BY b.cdt DESC)
```

Comment: i have edited my query, can you please look at it, i have checked the output provided by you. if you can see the result cdt if you see the time for id 5 and 6 19:17:.. and 19:18..are of same hour interval..it should get only one record which is highest of that interval if it falls within a 10 minute interval..i will update my answer with expected result..

Comment: In my first version I assumed that you wanted the grouping with respect to each brandname. I removed that in my second version. It does not change the output for the given sample data. As it turns out the samples for ID 5 and 6 belong to different days and therefore also to different intervals.

Comment: i have added a image with explanation can you please check that.

Comment: The title of your question was a bit misleading ... but if you want a 16-day interval check out my third edit above.