# how to modify sql query to get records based on user inputs of hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which will be updated every second with some data. I have designed a form where user can enter start date and end date, start time and end time and choose interval for which they want data. for example if they want todays records they will enter todays date in both textboxes and enter 1 hr 10 min 10 sec as the interval i need to get the data for the day (24 hrs) every 1 hr 10 min 10 sec last created record.

i am building query dynamically based on user inputs.

initial query before user enters "1 hr 10 min 10 sec"

```
SELECT t0.brandID, t0.brandName, t0.cdt, t0.udt, t0.brandstatus, t0.AddedBy  
FROM brands t0 WHERE  t0.cdt >= @VALUE1 and  t0.cdt <=@VALUE2
```

after user select "1 hr 10 min 10 sec"

```
 WITH CTE AS (SELECT *,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                                        PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, cdt)/10 ORDER BY cdt DESC) from brands)
    SELECT t0.brandID, t0.brandName, t0.cdt, t0.udt, t0.brandstatus, t0.AddedBy
      FROM cte t0 WHERE RN=1 AND  (t0.cdt >= '2013-11-01' and  t0.cdt <='2013-11-16')
```

the above query is giving me with 10 "Minute" interval how to change it for hour,min,sec

```
    brandid        brandname         cdt                   udt                     brandstatus      addedby
1              something  2013-11-01 00:00:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 00:01:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 00:02:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 00:03:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 00:04:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 00:05:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 00:06:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 00:07:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 00:08:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 00:09:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 00:10:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 01:01:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 00:02:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 00:03:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 00:30:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 02:10:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 03:00:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 03:01:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 03:02:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 03:03:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 03:15:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 03:20:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 04:10:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 05:10:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 06:21:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 07:51:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
1              something  2013-11-01 08:01:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
```

[image]

expected result for 1 hr 1 min 1 sec

```
 1             something  2013-11-01 01:01:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1

1              something  2013-11-01 01:30:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1

1              something  2013-11-01 02:10:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1

1              something  2013-11-01 03:20:01.123   2013-11-01 00:00:01.123        1               1
```

Comment: What is your Question.. Seems you are getting your require results right?

Comment: yeah, i am getting for only minute interval, if you see the image there is Generate for Every option is there if the user inputs only minute i am getting result, if the user inputs hours or seconds i am not getting result, for example if user inputs 1 hour 5 min and 30 seconds i should load the data for a time period of every 1 hour 5 min 30 seconds

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand at the moment - can you provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: is this sql server 2012 or later ?

Comment: its 2008 sql server, i think i am doing partionby minute need to add partition by hour,minute and sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the basic principal of the getting the group by interval as shown in your other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111482/how-to-get-highest-record-of-every-10-minute-data-sql-query/36111871#36111871) datediff() will returns an integer. And when integer divide by integer will gives you result in integer. So

```
10 / 10 = 1
11 / 10 = 1
. . .
19 / 10 = 1
```

Partition by that will give you a "interval" of 10 mins that you requried.

So if you need interval like 1 hour 5 mins, convert into minutes is 65 mins

And this will give you the interval of 1 hr 5 mins

```
PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, cdt) / 65
```

The problem is the seconds. If you need interval in terms of seconds, you will need to use `DATEDIFF (SECOND, 0, cdt)` that will result in overflow

Good thing you have a starting date `@VALUE1`. So you can use that as reference date instead of date 0

```
PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(SECOND, @VALUE1, cdt)
```

So putting it all together, and converting the required interval of 1 hr 5 min 10 sec into seconds

```
declare @interval int

select @interval =  (1 * 60 * 60) + (5 * 60) + (10)

PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(SECOND, @VALUE1, cdt) / @interval
```

that should do it